White box cuts into footer and only appears on mobile view. How do I get rid of it?
This white box appears at every footer but only on mobile view.It's cutting into my footer and I don't know what to do with it.  stupid box picture
Footer code
<footer class="w3-center w3-black w3-padding-64">
  <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <!--Disclaimer-->
    <h3 class="w3-center">Heatlh and Safety Disclaimer</h3>
    <p class="w3-center" style="font-size: 11px; height: 10px; color: white; position: relative;">
      Adults Only: The products available at our store are strictly for adult smokers (21+). You must be of legal smoking age in your region to purchase and use our products.
    
      Nicotine Warning: Be advised that certain items sold here may contain nicotine, a substance known for its addictive properties. Nicotine is an addictive chemical.
      
      California Proposition 65 Notice: California’s Proposition 65 mandates that we warn our customers that products sold here can expose you to chemicals including nicotine, which is known to the State of California to cause birth defects or other reproductive harm. For more information, please visit the Proposition 65 Warnings Website.
      
      Product Use and Safety: Our products are intended for use by adult smokers. Before using any product, please consult your physician, especially if you have any existing medical conditions.
      
      Ingredients in E-Liquids: E-Liquids available at our store may contain Propylene Glycol and/or Vegetable Glycerin, Nicotine, and Flavorings. Direct oral ingestion of these products can be harmful.
      
      FDA Disclaimer: The Food and Drug Administration has not evaluated the statements regarding these products. Their efficacy has not been confirmed by FDA-approved research. These products are not intended to diagnose, treat, cure, or prevent any disease. This information is not a substitute for professional medical advice.
      
      Safety Precautions: Always keep these products out of reach of children and pets to avoid accidental ingestion or other risks.
      
      Store Policy: We encourage you to review our store's terms and conditions before making a purchase. All products are used at your own risk.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative; top: -200px;">
    <a href="#home" class="w3-button w3-light-grey"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up w3-margin-right"></i>To the top</a>
    <p>click here for <a href="credits.html" title="Credits" target="_blank" class="w3-hover-text-green">Credits</a></p>
  </div>
  </footer>

tried using
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
html{overflow:auto; max-height: 100%;
}
}

It did not work

Which box are you talking about?

We can’t usefully help debug code we can’t see. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

If your website is live, can you please post a link to it?

I figured it out. it was an overflow issue.
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
footer {
    overflow: auto; /* or overflow: scroll; */
    height: auto; /* Adjust height as needed */
    padding-bottom: 20px; /* Add padding to ensure content is fully visible */
}

}
This is the only thing that worked.
